# React test redirect to same Route using Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a login Page I'm currently testing with JEST/Enzyme using this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

import { Button, FormControl } from 'react-bootstrap';

import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'
import { configure, mount } from 'enzyme';

import LoginScreen from'./index';

it('login page renders without crashing', () => {
  configure({adapter: new Adapter()});
  let page =
  <Router>
    <LoginScreen />  
  </Router>;
  let mountedpage = mount(page);

  let btn = mountedpage.find(Button);
  let loginscreen;
  let frm = mountedpage.find(FormControl);

  frm.forEach(async (node) => {
    node.simulate('change', {value: 'e'});
    node.simulate('keypress', {key: 'e'});
    node.simulate('keypress', {key: 'Enter'});
  });

  loginscreen = mountedpage.find(LoginScreen);
  loginscreen.setState({mail: "test", pass: "123"});
  btn = mountedpage.find(Button);
  btn.simulate('click');
  });
```

When btn.simulate('click') is called, the login is successfull and redirects to "/". Usually the loginpage is hosted at "/login" so there are no problems.
But apperantly Enzyme emulates the page at URL "/", so I get a warning:

```
console.error node_modules/warning/warning.js:34
Warning: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/"
```

Is there any way I can tell Enzyme that it should emulate to be at "/login" by default?